# PHP - Why the void function is not transforming an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I want to add another array after doing some filters, I wanted to use a void function but it didn't transform the array.

Here is my code:

```
$report = [];

$firstHeaders = ['a','b','c'];
$fieldHeaders = ['d','e','f'];
$lastHeaders = ['x','y','z'];

$this->makeHeaders($report, $firstHeaders, $fieldHeaders, $lastHeaders);

var_dump($report);

private function makeHeaders($report, $firstHeaders, $fieldHeaders, $lastHeaders): void {
  foreach ($firstHeaders as $firstHeader) {
    array_push($report['headers'], $firstHeader);
  }
  foreach ($fieldHeaders as $fieldHeader) {
    array_push($report['headers'], $fieldHeader);
  }
  foreach ($lastHeaders as $lastHeader) {
    array_push($report['headers'], $lastHeader);
  }  
}
```

The var_dump gives me an empty array when what I want is the following:

```
$report['headers'] = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','x','y','z']
```

I can make it work if the return type is array but why is the void function not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `$report` to be passed by reference using `&`:

```
private function makeHeaders(&$report, $firstHeaders, $fieldHeaders, $lastHeaders): void {
```

See [PHP: Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Optionally, if you define `$report` as a class variable then all you need is:

```
private function makeHeaders($firstHeaders, $fieldHeaders, $lastHeaders): void {
```

To access it like:

```
array_push($this->report['headers'], $firstHeader);
```

Or without `array_push()`:

```
$this->report['headers'][] = $firstHeader;
```

However, depending on your array keys this may do it without the loops:

```
$report["headers"] = array_merge($firstHeaders,
                                 $fieldHeaders,
                                 $lastHeaders);
```

Comment: This was it! But I also needed to declare `$report['headers']` before the first for-each in the function or before calling the function, otherwise, it will return null.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that if you use this instead of `array_push` : `$report['headers'][] = $firstHeader;` etc...

Comment: which one is a cleaner approach? `array_push` or `$array[] = 'foo'`

Comment: I never use `array_push` and I think most developers/frameworks/libraries use `$array[] = 'foo';`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this isn't a direct answer, but as an alternative to consider, maybe using [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$report = [];

$firstHeaders = ['a','b','c'];
$fieldHeaders = ['d','e','f'];
$lastHeaders = ['x','y','z'];

$report["headers"] = array_merge($firstHeaders,$fieldHeaders,$lastHeaders);

var_dump($report);
```

Results in

```
array(1) {
  ["headers"]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "d"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "e"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "f"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "x"
    [7]=>
    string(1) "y"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "z"
  }
}
```